# How to find the file to a particular resource that it belongs in eclipse for Android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I have many xml files in my project.

I want to find out R.id.details belongs to which xml file.

How do I find it in eclipse?

Comment: They don't belong to any XML file. They are defined in Java file that for example Eclipse automatically generates under your project in package R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources you would be using in an activity would be of the same xml file which you will set in 
setContentView(abc.xml);

Comment: Right, actually I had two layout files, for potrait and landscape, which caused the confusion.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In latetst indigo version of eclilpe and latest adt .. I'  ve checked whenever when you place your mouse's cursor on the R.id.xxxx statement it will give you the available files in which it is declared. Hope this can solve your issue